# What happenned at Ripon - Weston Elementary School

Tags: cancer, electromagnetism, school, radio

### Links / news

- [Did the radio tower cause the cancer?](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/cell-tower-shut-down-some-california-parents-link-to-several-cases-of-childhood-cancer/) - There is little evidence that radio towers in general cause cancer.
- [Tests reveal carcinogen (TCE) in tap water](https://www.modbee.com/news/local/article235563337.html) but carcinogen is 10x lower than the legal limit (0.56mg/l  where legal limit is 5mg/l). [More info.](https://sacramento.cbslocal.com/2019/05/02/moms-kids-cancer-cell-tower-water-ripon/)

### Types of cancer observed:

The 4 children who obtained cancer had the following types of cancers:

- Kidney Cancer
- Brain Cancer
- 2 more unknown

The mothers also compiled a list of cancers occurring in their area which include:

- Breast cancer
- Leukemia
- Liver cancer
- Kidney Cancer
- ...

I definitely find it odd the 2 boys (who were friends) both got cancer. This seems greatly unusual, but not impossible. I'd think it was more about some activity the 2 boys did together, maybe without their parents knowledge, but that'd be more speculation.

### Cancers caused by radiation (from googling):

- Lung cancer - from breathing in radon
- Skin cancer - exposure to ionising radiation

In theory other forms of cancer could be seen from ionising radiation but I did some maths and found that exposure to the sun for 1 day is comparable to 27 years near a mobile phone. So the idea that the cancer was caused by radiation seems somewhat impossible to me.

### Cancers caused by TCE (from [paper](https://academic.oup.com/jnci/article/105/12/869/904951)):

- Kidney cancer
- Non-Hodgkin lymphoma
- Liver cancer
- Cervical cancer
- Esophageal adrenocarinoma

### [Most common causes of kidney cancer](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/kidney-cancer/symptoms-causes/syc-20352664)

- Cadmium
- "Specific herbicides"

### [Most common causes of brain cancer](https://www.healthline.com/health/brain-cancer#causes-and-risk-factors)

- Exposure to "Pesticides, Herbicides, Fertilizer"
- Working with elements that can cause cancer, such as lead, plastic, rubber, petroleum, and some textiles
- Having an Epstein-Barr virus infection, or mononucleosis

### Most common causes of "cancer"

I generally don't like to say there is a cause of "cancer" because cancer is such a catch-all/generic phrase... But...

According to [cancer.org](https://www.cancer.org/cancer/cancer-causes.html)

- Smoking and Tobacco
- Diet and Physical Activity
- Sun and Other Types of Radiation
- Viruses and Other Infections
- Genetic causes

Are the most common causes of cancer

### What do you think?

All the information here seems very disjointed. TCE could have caused one of the children's kidney cancer. But at the same time cancer isn't uncommon, according to cancer.org 4 out of 10 people will get cancer at some point in their lives.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: I think the jury is still out: https://sacramento.cbslocal.com/2019/09/26/cancer-causing-chemical-found-ripon-soil-vapor-not-one-parents-expected/

Comment: The end of this seems to be worded as if it's looking for opinions or discussions, which aren't really on topic on this site.  I would suggest rewording that a bit.  See the help centre for more details https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: There is another possibility: radioctive particles dumped on the land by the 1957 [Windscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windscale_fire) and 1986 [Chernobyl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernobyl_disaster) fires. Although the UK government tried to air-brush it away (by renaming the plant as Sellafield and saying most of the radioactivity was Iodine-131 with a half-life of only 8 days) there were other isotopes too, which may have lingered, and it's possible the two boys liked one such spot. Perhaps the wind blew a particle into a crevice which somehow never gets washed by the rain.

Comment: What's the notable claim that you doubt? Two kids got cancer? Is that it?

Comment: @WeatherVane - You're saying that incidents in Britain and Ukraine caused cancer in kids in California?????

Comment: @DanielRHicks I am saying that there have been numerous leaks of radioactive particles, some in America, and you can be fairly sure that not all were recorded, or were worse than admitted. Although they will follow the wind direction, they can end up anywhere in the hemisphere (there isn't so much air movement between the hemispheres). Looking at it the other way, it is difficult to see how these emission can have had **no** effect on cancer rates, and in the vicinity of, say, Chernobyl they certainly did. Look at the Krakatoa explosion: ash went over the entire world.

Comment: Co-incidences happen all the time. Children get cancer all the time. Sometimes, by co-incidence, a bunch of them happen to be in the same school. The odds of this happening to any one school are very low, but there are a lot of schools in America. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_illusion